# PowerShell DSC not creating a MOF

Tags: powershell, dsc

I am currently learning about DSC and trying to create my first MOF file. When i run my Configuration script there is no MOF File created or errors reported. I am trying this on a windows 10 machine, not sure if that is the problem.

Here is the script. It is very simple just wanted something to test the basics first. Any help or suggestions would be great.

```
Configuration TestDSC
{
    Node GMSMS01
    {
        File FileExample
        {
            Ensure = "Present"
            Type = "Directory"
            Recurse = $true
            SourcePath = "D:\Temp\Source"
            DestinationPath = "D:\Temp\Target"
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to invoke the `configuration` you declared, as it would a PowerShell function, e.g.put after the declaration this invokation:

> TestDSC

to invoke it and get the MOF files.